# Customizing itemize inside a node in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, itemize

I am working with the MWE below and I am trying to do something that seems to be easy, but I cannot figure out.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (B) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}};


    \node[circle, fill=red!50!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (nuc) at (B) {};
    \node[circle, fill=red!50!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (cyt) at ($(B)+(.4,.4)$) {};
    \node[circle, fill=green!25!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (cha) at ($(B)+(.8,-.6)$) {};
    \node[circle, fill=green!25!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (mem) at ($(B)+(.4,-1)$) {};


    \node[right=1cm of B.north east, align=left, text width=3cm, font=\tiny, fill=yellow] (C1) {
        \begin{itemize}
         \item RNA processing
         \item DNA repair
         \item cell cycle regulation
         \item cellular component organization
         \item metabolic pathways
        \end{itemize}
    };
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}, color=red!50!black] (C1.north west) -- (C1.south west) node[midway] {};

    \node[right=0.5cm of B.east, align=left, shift={(0cm,-1.5cm)}, text width=4cm, font=\tiny, fill=yellow] (C2) {
        \begin{itemize}
         \item bind growth factors, receptors and metal ions
         \item cell signaling and communication
         \item cell migration, motility, localization and adhesion
        \end{itemize}
    };
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}, color=green!25!black] (C2.north west) -- (C2.south west) node[midway] {};

    \path[->, >=latex, red!50!black, opacity=.6, line width=1pt] {[out=350,in=180]
        (nuc) edge ($(C1.west)-(.2,0)$)
        (cyt) edge ($(C1.west)-(.2,0)$)};
    \path[->, >=latex, green!25!black, opacity=.6, line width=1pt] {[out=350,in=180]
        (cha) edge ($(C2.west)-(.2,0)$)
        (mem) edge ($(C2.west)-(.2,0)$)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:
[image]

I would just want:

1. Red text in the upper yellow box and green text in the lower one
2. Red and green circle for each item
3. No vertical space between items
4. No indentation for the items
5. No horizontal space between item circle and text

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For 1, 2: use `\begin{itemize}\color{red}` and `\begin{itemize}\color{green}`

Comment: Do you mean vertical in 3? What else goes on this slide? Anything?

Comment: Use `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]` after the start of the frame but before the start of the picture for circles. Use `\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red!50!black}\color{red!50!black}` before `\begin{itemize}` for the colour. This will change the curly bracket's colour as well which I suspect you want here. Use the `squeeze` frame option to eliminate vertical space between items (if that's what you meant in 3).

Comment: @cfr yes vertical, sorry. The slide only has text above and another image at the left...

Comment: I asked about what else because `squeeze` will affect the whole slide so it might be problematic if you had another itemize, say, where you wanted the inter-item space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing a little bit with:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red!50!black}\color{red!50!black}

\setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}

\setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}

\color{red!50!black}

\itemsep1pt
```

I came up with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
    \node (B) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}};


    \node[circle, fill=red!50!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (nuc) at (B) {};
    \node[circle, fill=red!50!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (cyt) at ($(B)+(.4,.4)$) {};
    \node[circle, fill=green!25!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (cha) at ($(B)+(.8,-.6)$) {};
    \node[circle, fill=green!25!black, opacity=.5, minimum size=.4cm] (mem) at ($(B)+(.4,-1)$) {};


    \node[right=1cm of B.north east, align=left, text width=3.2cm, font=\tiny, fill=yellow] (C1) {
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
    \setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red!50!black}\color{red!50!black}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}
        \begin{itemize}
        \color{red!50!black}
        \itemsep1pt
            \item RNA processing
            \item DNA repair
            \item cell cycle regulation
            \item cellular component organization
            \item metabolic pathways
        \end{itemize}
    };
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}, color=red!50!black] (C1.north west) -- (C1.south west) node[midway] {};

    \node[right=0.5cm of B.east, align=left, shift={(0cm,-1.5cm)}, text width=4.8cm, font=\tiny, fill=yellow] (C2) {
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
        \setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=green!25!black}\color{red!50!black}
        \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}
        \begin{itemize}
        \color{green!25!black}
        \itemsep1pt
            \item bind growth factors, receptors and metal ions
            \item cell signaling and communication
            \item cell migration, motility, localization and adhesion
        \end{itemize}
    };
    \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}, color=green!25!black] (C2.north west) -- (C2.south west) node[midway] {};

    \path[->, >=latex, red!50!black, opacity=.6, line width=1pt] {[out=350,in=180]
        (nuc) edge ($(C1.west)-(.2,0)$)
        (cyt) edge ($(C1.west)-(.2,0)$)};
    \path[->, >=latex, green!25!black, opacity=.6, line width=1pt] {[out=350,in=180]
        (cha) edge ($(C2.west)-(.2,0)$)
        (mem) edge ($(C2.west)-(.2,0)$)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following:
[image]

It seems, though, like item symbols are not aligned with the text... Is it me, or are they clearly above the text? Is there a way to solve it?