# Fix itemize indexing without enumitem

Tags: beamer, itemize, enumitem

I have a really large tikz image which is difficult to fit onto one single page. My workaround was to load enumitem, but that makes my list crash:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}


%\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

%\sisetup {
    %locale = DE,
    %per-mode = symbol
%}

% THEME AND COLOR SETUP
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{27. June 2018}

\mode<presentation>{}


\tikzset{start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
         text width=16mm, text=black, minimum height=23mm, font=\tiny,
         signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
     cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west, text=black}
    }

\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\title{MS Powerpoint and TeX}
\author{Narusan}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Revision}
        \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm,
         start chain = going right,
         mylabel/.style={anchor=north west,font=\bfseries\tiny, color=black}
             ]

    \node[start=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Meldebogen}] {
        \begin{itemize} 
                \item {\color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}}
                 \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
        \end{itemize}   
            };
    \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Anklage}] {    \begin{itemize}
                    \item \color{black}{Einflussreiche Nazis konnten Anklage entgehen}
                \end{itemize} 
         };
    \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Beweisaufnahme}] {
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item \color{black}{Kl\"{a}ger ermittelt kaum}
                    \item Persilscheine
                    \item Zeitdruck
                \end{itemize}   
            };
    \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Urteil}] {
             \begin{itemize}
                    \item\color{black}{Gerichte nicht unabh\"{a}ngig}
                    \item Laiengerichte
                    \item \"{o}ffentlicher Druck
            \end{itemize}  
    };
    \node[cont=darkred!80!black, label={[mylabel]north west:Revision}] {  
            \begin{itemize}
                        \item \color{black}{Gerichte sind im Nachhinein oft nachl\"{a}ssig}
                        \item Einstufung aufgrund wirtschaftlicher Bedenken
                    \end{itemize}  
                        };      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you load enumitem because of `leftmargin=*`, right?

Comment: Exactly, only option I found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the workaround from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192270).

[image: items]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}

% THEME AND COLOR SETUP
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{27. June 2018}

\tikzset{start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
        text width=16mm, text=black, minimum height=23mm, font=\tiny,
        signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
    cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west, text=black}
}


\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}  
    \title{MS Powerpoint and TeX}
    \author{Narusan}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Revision}
    \begin{center}
        \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm,
        start chain = going right,
        mylabel/.style={anchor=north west,font=\bfseries\tiny, color=black}
        ]

        \node[start=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Meldebogen}] {
            \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}}
            \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
            \end{itemize}   
        };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Anklage}] {    \begin{itemize}
            \item \color{black}{Einflussreiche Nazis konnten Anklage entgehen}
            \end{itemize} 
        };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Beweisaufnahme}] {
            \begin{itemize}
            \item \color{black}{Kl\"{a}ger ermittelt kaum}
            \item Persilscheine
            \item Zeitdruck
            \end{itemize}   
        };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Urteil}] {
            \begin{itemize}
            \item\color{black}{Gerichte nicht unabh\"{a}ngig}
            \item Laiengerichte
            \item \"{o}ffentlicher Druck
            \end{itemize}  
        };
        \node[cont=darkred!80!black, label={[mylabel]north west:Revision}] {  
            \begin{itemize}
            \item \color{black}{Gerichte sind im Nachhinein oft nachl\"{a}ssig}
            \item Einstufung aufgrund wirtschaftlicher Bedenken
            \end{itemize}  
        };      
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```